# Certain Poisson prob for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, poisson

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qROd1.png). What formula should be used so that the number in cell A4 corresponds to a certain Poisson probability (highlighted in yellow and =0.8) from the data range in column "B"?

By hand, I made a table next to it. The number should be 99 for probability =0.8. But how do I find it with one formula for column "B"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=let(Σ,sequence(max(B:B)-min(B:B)+1,1,max(B:B),-1),
   xlookup(A2,index(poisson(Σ,average(B:B),1)),Σ,,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the formula for you test it out.